# Automapper and Url.Content

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, automapper

I have an MVC5 controller that converts a DTO to a ViewModel.

```
model.Items = items.Select(i => new MovieSearchItem
{
    Id = i.Id,
    Image = (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(i.Image) ? @Url.Content("~/Content/noMovieImage.png") : i.Image),
    Title = i.Title
}).ToList();
```

I'm trying to do the same using Automapper.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<MovieDTO, MovieSearchItem>()
    .ForMember(m => m.Image,
        opt => opt.MapFrom(src => GetConversionForMovieSearchItem()(src)));
```

And the function called is:

```
public Func<MovieDTO, string> GetConversionForMovieSearchItem()
{
    return new Func<MovieDTO, string>(src =>
    {
        var image = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(src.Image) ? @Url.Content("~/Content/noMovieImage.png")
                            : src.Image;
        return image;
    });
}
```

When the mapping is performed, an exception is thrown:

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Value does not fall within the expected range.

And the stack trace is:

```
at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(Int32 errorCode)
   at System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.GetServerVariableInternal(String name)
   at System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.GetServerVariable(String name)
   at System.Web.WebPages.UrlRewriterHelper.WasThisRequestRewritten(HttpContextBase httpContext)
   at System.Web.WebPages.UrlRewriterHelper.WasRequestRewritten(HttpContextBase httpContext)
   at System.Web.WebPages.UrlUtil.GenerateClientUrlInternal(HttpContextBase httpContext, String contentPath)
   at System.Web.WebPages.UrlUtil.GenerateClientUrlInternal(HttpContextBase httpContext, String contentPath)
   at System.Web.WebPages.UrlUtil.GenerateClientUrl(HttpContextBase httpContext, String contentPath)
   at System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper.GenerateContentUrl(String contentPath, HttpContextBase httpContext)
   at Pinicules.Presentation.Controllers.MoviesController.<GetConversionForMovieSearchItem>b__0(MovieDTO src) in c:\Repositories\GitHub\Pinicules\Pinicules.Presentation\Controllers\MoviesController.cs:line 23
   at lambda_method(Closure , MovieDTO )
   at AutoMapper.DelegateBasedResolver`2.Resolve(ResolutionResult source)
   at AutoMapper.NullReferenceExceptionSwallowingResolver.Resolve(ResolutionResult source)
   at AutoMapper.PropertyMap.<ResolveValue>b__6(ResolutionResult current, IValueResolver resolver)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Aggregate[TSource,TAccumulate](IEnumerable`1 source, TAccumulate seed, Func`3 func)
   at AutoMapper.PropertyMap.ResolveValue(ResolutionContext context)
   at AutoMapper.Mappers.TypeMapObjectMapperRegistry.PropertyMapMappingStrategy.MapPropertyValue(ResolutionContext context, IMappingEngineRunner mapper, Object mappedObject, PropertyMap propertyMap)
```

Why is this error happening? Why can I do to be able to use Automapper?

Thanks!

Comment: What does your view model look like?

Comment: `public class MovieSearchItem
 {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
 }`

It seems a problem with using Url.Content inside the conversion, but I don't understand why I can't use it.